# Why does Hayate have to cover herself when she enters and leaves Saint's Church?

Tags: nanoha

In the scene where Hayate goes to visit Carin after the formation of Riot Force 6 (episode 5 or 6 of *StrikerS*), when she enters Carin's office, she is seen wearing a shawl, the same kind shown to be worn by people outside moments before. However, when the two are talking, Hayate has taken it off.

When an alert about Gadget Drones' attack comes in, she is seen putting it back on in a hurry before she leaves. Why does she need to wear it outside Carim's office?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably customary, just like it is a custom in some Christian churches that a woman is expected to cover her head when entering a church building, especially during the services.

The Sankt Kaiser Church is modeled after Christianity in general and the Catholic Church in particular. It also has an autonomous area on Mid-Childa; compare the Vatican city state. (There even exists a counterpart of the Turin shroud.)